# Change level into list in org mode

Tags: org-mode, list

I have following text which are expressed in level 5

```
***** It's better to be first than it is to be better.
***** The basic issue in marketing is creating a category you can be first in. It’s the law of leadership: It’s
      better to be first than it is to be better.
***** It’s much easier to get into the mind first than to try to convince someone you have a better product than the
      one that did get there first.
```

........

I want to change into list

```
00001 It's better to be first than it is to be better.
00002 The basic issue in marketing is creating a category you can be first in. It’s the law of leadership: It’s
      better to be first than it is to be better.
00003 It’s much easier to get into the mind first than to try to convince someone you have a better product than the
      one that did get there first.
```

Is there any quick way to do that?

Comment: Does this query replace regexp get what you want?: Search for "`^\*+\(\s-+.*\)`" and replace with "`\,(format "%05d" \#)\1`".

Comment: It can get even more fancy by changing the replacement expression to "`\,(format (concat "%0" (number-to-string (org-current-level)) "d") \#)\1`" :)

Comment: Cool! I'll convert that to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the in-built `query-replace-regexp` function to do this kind of text manipulation. By default, it is bound to `C-M-%`.

So you would do `C-M-%`,

- enter "`^\*+\(\s-+.*\)`" in the *Query replace regexp:* field, and
- "`\,(format (concat "%0" (number-to-string (org-current-level)) "d") (1+ \#))\1`" in the *with:* field.

---

Above will convert

```
* abc
** def
*** ghi
**** jkl
***** mno
****** pqr
******* stu
******** vwx
********* yz
```

to

```
1 abc
02 def
003 ghi
0004 jkl
00005 mno
000006 pqr
0000007 stu
00000008 vwx
000000009 yz
```

---

**NOTE**: If you want to deal with only level-5 headings, you can have the search regexp and replace strings as "`^\*\{5\}\(\s-+.*\)`" and "`\,(format "%05d" (1+ \#))\1`".

---

When applying either of the above two solutions on your example, the result is the exact same as you have in the question.